# Angular POST to Node Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mongodb

I am trying to learn angular and I have run into a problem. I have a form that submits an Item Name, Price, and Image to MongoDB. In my Node route I am using res.json as the response. While using the jQuery POST method I can stay on the page and return the data to the console or a variable or whatever. When I changed to the angular POST method I am actually going to a new page that contains the JSON response. This of course is not what I want. I want to update the database, GET the new data, and update the model without ever leaving the page.

**This is my node route.**

```
router.post('/items/add', function(req, res){
    // handle image upload
    fs.readFile(req.files.image.path, function (err, data) {

        var imageName = req.files.image.name

        /// If there's an error
        if(!imageName){

            console.log("There was an error")
            res.redirect("/");
            res.end();

        } else {
            var newPath = '/uploads/' + imageName;
          /// write file to uploads/fullsize folder
          fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {

          });
        }
    });

    // save info to database
    var newItem = new Item({
        name : req.param('Name'), 
        price : req.param('Price'),
        image : req.files.image.name
    });
    newItem.save(function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else{
            Item.find(function(err, items){
                if (err){
                    return console.log(err);
                } else{

                    res.json({
                        items : items
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**This is my angular code:**

```
var allItems = angular.module('allItems', []);

allItems.controller('allItemsCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.updateItems = function(){
        $http.get('/allItems').success(function(data){
            $scope.theitems = data.allItems;
        });
    };

    // The culprit
    $scope.postItems = function(){
        $scope.formData = {};
        $http.post('/items/add', formData).success(function(data){
            $scope.theitems = data.allItems;
        });
    };

    $scope.updateItems();
});
```

The data is POSTing correctly, however I want it to act like an AJAX post and not leave the page. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: The real question is how on earth did you manage to make an Angular `$http.post()` request **not** act like a AJAX request ! How are you invoking `$scope.postItems()` ?

Comment: I am using ng-submit, but i must be doing something wrong, because you are right it should be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a real HTML form with a submit button like this

```
<form method="post" action="http://yoursite.com/items">
  <input type="text"/>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

then it will do a page refresh regardless of what you end up doing in your JavaScript. I would keep the HTML form element so it's semantically correct but you don't need the method or action attributes. Instead use [ngSubmit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) on your form like this

```
<form ng-submit="postItems()">
  <input type="text"/>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```